# Return specific elements in array with .filter?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn some functional programming principles in javascript, but having some issues. I understand the iterative method (just a for loop), but I wanted to know if there was a functional programming style solution.

Say we have an array `A` where each element of `A` is another array, let's call these elements `a`:

```
A: [ Array[28], Array[28], ... ], where a_1..a_n is an array of size 28
```

Now say I only want the `5th element` within `a` (so `a[4]`).

How would I do that using one of the higher order functions such as `.map, .filter` etc?

I've tried a method as such:

```
function myMethodThatReturns5thElem(n) {
 return n[4];
}

var arrayThatHas5thElements = A.filter(myMethodThatReturns5thElem);
```

but then `arrayThatHas5thElements`is the same exact array as `A`..

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to use the second parameter inside the `.filter` function, which is `index` - `A.filter(function(innerArray, index) { return index === 4 });`

Comment: but arent' those the indexes of the individual arrays? I really only want the 4th element WITHIN those individual arrays

Comment: Ohhh! Sounds like you want `.map`... `A.map(function(inner) { return inner[4] });`

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `.map` to return specific parts of the array:

```
var subset = A.map(function(inner) {
    return inner[4];
});
```

And if you want a single array - rather than a bunch of inner arrays with 1 element - just flatten the result:

```
var subsetFlattened = A.map(function(inner) {
    return inner[4];
}).reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
    return p.concat(c);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.filter(callback)
```

the **callback** function:

Returns *true* to keep the element, *false* otherwise.

So this means that your function `arrayThatHas4thElement` should return true in the when the item is the forth element

callback function receives 3 arguments:

- `value` of the element
- `index` of the element

You could use the 2nd parameter to evaluate what you are looking for.